# formatting return from http request python

Tags: python, http, parsing, request, url-encoding

I'm trying to write a python script which will retrieve values from a http server and change the data into csv format, I am using the httplib2 library to preform the request, but my problem is the return for the content is in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format, I have code for parsing the the data as a dict, but can't seem to do anything with it as this kind of string, I know it might seem simple to extensive users, as I can't seem to find any info on this through research...

below is a sample code, just to illustrate the type of thing I'm trying to do and my problem

```
import httplib2
http = httplib2.Http()

resp, content = http.request("http://example.com/foo/bar")
```

Thank you for the Help

btw I'm using python 2.7 and the format the request naturally returns is json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are receiving an encoded response, you can use `urllib.unquote` to replace the escaped characters into their 'actual' representation. Once you do that, you can use the `json` module to load the string as a Python object and then use the `csv` module to create a CSV based on the response. The structure of your response will govern how this will be set up on your end, but hopefully this will get you on the right path:

```
In [1]: import csv

In [2]: import json

In [3]: import urllib

In [4]: json_resp = urllib.quote('[{"name": "John Doe", "age": 35}, {"name": "Jane Doe", "age": 33}]')

In [5]: json_resp # What I believe your response looks like
Out[5]: '%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22John%20Doe%22%2C%20%22age%22%3A%2035%7D%2C%20%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Jane%20Doe%22%2C%20%22age%22%3A%2033%7D%5D'

In [6]: resp = urllib.unquote(json_resp) #'Unquote' the response

In [7]: resp
Out[7]: '[{"name": "John Doe", "age": 35}, {"name": "Jane Doe", "age": 33}]'

In [8]: content = json.loads(resp) # Turn the resp into a Python object

In [9]: fieldnames = ('name', 'age') # Specify the order in which to write fields

In [10]: with open('mycsv.csv', 'wb') as f:
   ....:     writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames)
   ....:     writer.writeheader() # Python 2.7+
   ....:     for item in content:
   ....:         writer.writerow(item)
   ....:
   ....:
```

This will write a CSV that looks like:

```
name,age
John Doe,35
Jane Doe,33
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have upped it as it is a very good answer, although I should have specified that the 'content' I receive, looks like json to me, I'm hesitant to post the exact response as it's invoices I'm retrieving. but It looks like your out on line 7, with another two dimensions, although if I try passing it into the json.loads() function it returns a ValueError: No Json object... this seems to be very weird, I've tried every other solution I could find on the web

Comment: @jbaldwin Ah gotcha, that, makes it a bit simpler then :) So one thing to check would be the response itself - does it appear to be in a valid format, meaning are double-quotes used to enclose paratmers, are all `{`'s matched with closing `}`'s, all lists properly closed, no extra commas, etc. You can test your current technique with a basic, valid JSON string (like the example above) - if it works, it will be an issue with the response itself.

Comment: I have used a json 'checker' someone linked to on a forum somewhere, http://jsonlint.com/ when I put my code in here it says "Parse error on line 45:
...               "v": (2010,             
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['"   but I don't know much about java, when I have looked at this in a view diffeent ways, sometimes I get newDate(2010... then when I looked this up, it said that it is used for data format, so would the formatting of the data still work?

Comment: but the version I am pulling in my script is  {'v': (2010, 0, 24, 21, 51, 34) format

Comment: @jbaldwin So that value alone (`(2010, 0, 24, 21, 51, 34)`) looks like it will cause the error as it isn't enclosed in quotes (and since the basic JSON decoder does not convert tuple-like representations to tuples (I'm guessing this may be due to it not being valid JavaScript, but I'm not super familiar with JS so probably disregard that :) ). Can you control the response you receive?

Comment: I don't have control over the server responses, but from what your'e saying, surely if I wrap the section in quotes it should work, although it doesn't.

Comment: @jbaldwin On its own, `json.loads('{"v": "(2010, 0, 24, 21, 51, 34)"}')` works for me - does it not for you? In any case, that looks like the main issue - that appears to be a datetime object (January 24, 2010 at 21:51:34) that is not being properly encoded.

Comment: it's format is a string, would you know anyway of turning it into a muilty D dict? which I could then just loop through? there is no reason I need a json object

Comment: @jbaldwin Actually, if you have it as a string already, try using the `ast` module. Drop in `import ast` at the top, and if your string is stored in `resp`, use something like `parsed_resp = ast.literal_eval(resp)`. This will evaluate the string into its corresponding Python objects (tuples included), and it should handle your response (at least it handles `{"v": (2010, 0, 24, 21, 51, 34)}` without doing anything special :) ).

Comment: when I try that I get:return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST) File "<unknown>", line 1
{ "cols": [{ "label": "unique_id", "type": "string"},...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @jbaldwin Hmm, can you tell where the incorrect syntax may be? Does any of it look like invalid Python? This seems like it is definitely an issue with the response - if we can figure out where the issue is then we can think of a way to get around it

Comment: It is the first 'new date(2010...' I'm sorry about all the trouble, but thank you so much.  but when I try the same code on the small '{"v": "new Date(2010, 0, 24, 21, 51, 34)"}' it works fine...

Comment: @jbaldwin No worries :) Hmm, alright let me think on that for a bit - that is the constructor for a JavaScript `Date` object, which would ideally be written as a string in this case. There will be a way around it, so I'm sure we can get it sorted :)

Comment: I would like to test if surrounding new date(2010... ) with quotes would work, but cant think of a way to insert the second quotes, it is not the only time brackets are used in the response

Comment: @jbaldwin Ha, one dirty (and probably unadvised/wrong :) ) solution would be to do a blanket remove of all `new Date` instances (replace with `''`), and then assuming you knew where the dates would be, unpacking the tuples into `datetime.date`, which seems to work in a simple test for me. As for doing that kind of replace, take a look at `re.sub` (in the `re` module) - it lets you do more specific substitutions.

Comment: I feel so stupid, after researching the API I was accessing, I found that I could use the parameter to change the date format to dateasepoch -_- then it worked perfectly, I'm so sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: @Baldwin Haha, always nice when there is a hidden easy way! And don't feel stupid - more than once I've made some complicated workaround only to find a simple way existed all along. Good luck with everything!